# Конвертация данных из csv в дату в R

Tags: дата, r

В R загружены данные из `csv` файла. Необходимо колонку `Date` преобразовать в дату формата `"дд/мм/гггг".`

При загрузке из `csv` файла дата запись в колонке дата выглядит так `02.01.2016.`

Попытка преобразовать следующим выражением:

```
date_SaleData <- as.Date(SaleData$Date, "%dd/%mm/%yyyy")
```

Приводит к тому что при просмотре `date_SaleData` там оказываются одни `"NA"`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы задаёте некорректный формат (шаблон) даты. Корректные значения можно посмотреть на странице справки к функции `strptime`. Если данные имеют вид `DD.MM.YYYY`, то при парсинге и надо указывать в точности этот формат, но испольховать при этом корректные обозначения.

```
str(as.Date("12.03.2016", "%d.%m.%Y"))
#> Date[1:1], format: "2016-03-12"
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо, помогло. Только почему необходимо ещё было заменить точки на слэши.

Comment: Если в данных точки, указываете в формате парсинга точки. Если слэши, то указываете слэши.